# Concatenation of fields in different rows

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate, string-concatenation

I'm stuck on an aggregation problem that I can't get to the bottom of.

I have some data which is best summarized as follows

```
id |phraseId|seqNum|word
=========================
1  |1       |1     |hello
2  |1       |2     |world
3  |2       |1     |black
4  |2       |2     |and
5  |2       |3     |white
```

I'd like a query that gives back the following data:

```
phraseId|completePhrase
========================
1       |hello world
2       |black and white
```

Anyone?

## EDIT

I notice all the provided solutions use `FOR XML PATH`. What is this magic?

Comment: there are a few ways : http://www.projectdmx.com/tsql/rowconcatenate.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to create an [UDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164062.aspx) using an [FOR XML PATH](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/06/01/60220.aspx) expression.

- the UDF handles the concatenation of one PhraseID
- it can be used in a normal select

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  PhraseID, dbo.UDF_ConcatWord(PhraseID)
FROM    Phrases
GROUP BY PhraseID
```

**Creating the UDF**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UDF_ConcatWord(@phraseID INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) AS
BEGIN  
  DECLARE @r VARCHAR(8000)
  SELECT @r = (
    SELECT  word + ', '
    FROM    Phrases
    WHERE   phraseID = @phraseID
    FOR XML PATH('')
  )
  IF LEN(@r) > 0 SET @r = SUBSTRING(@r, 1, LEN(@r)-1)
  RETURN @r
END
GO
```

### edit

After revising some of the links myself, an even shorter solution is

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  DISTINCT p1.PhraseID
        , STUFF(( SELECT  ' ' + p2.word 
                  FROM    Phrases AS p2 
                  WHERE   p2.PhraseID = p1.PhraseID 
                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS completePhrase
FROM      Phrases AS p1
ORDER BY  p1.PhraseID
```

Comment: I saw the cross join answer & your UDF, so I modified my parent-child answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342811/multiple-results-for-one-field-in-a-joined-sql-query/2343166#2343166 Then I noticed your edit, which is almost the same as mine. I was checking the execution plans to see if there was a difference, and mine was slower because I sort when combining the strings & you don't.  If the data is inserted out of order, your words will be in the wrong order. Adding a sort to your query makes it TotalSubtreeCost slower by 0.00000105, which must be the diff between GROUP BY vs DISTINCT.

Comment: OK. Thanks for all the answers. I've gone with this form, but they were all excellent. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
DECLARE @TableA  table (RowID int, phraseId varchar(5),seqNum int, word varchar(5))

INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES (1,1,1,'hello')
INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES (2,1,2,'world')
INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES (3,2,1,'black')
INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES (4,2,2,'and')
INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES (5,2,3,'white')

SELECT
    c1.phraseId
        ,STUFF(
                 (SELECT
                      ' ' + word
                      FROM @TableA  c2
                      WHERE c2.phraseId=c1.phraseId
                      ORDER BY c1.phraseId, seqNum
                      FOR XML PATH('') 
                 )
                 ,1,1, ''
              ) AS CombinedValue
    FROM @TableA c1
    GROUP BY c1.phraseId
    ORDER BY c1.phraseId
```

OUTPUT:

```
phraseId CombinedValue
-------- --------------------------
1        hello world
2        black and white

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have cheated a bit by assuming that you have a table which holds the header record for each phrase. If this is missing, you could construct it by selecting a distinct list of phraseIDs from the table containing the words:

```
declare @words table
(id int
,phraseId int
,seqNum int
,word varchar(10)
)

insert @words
select 1,1,1,'hello'
union select 2,1,2,'world'
union select 3,2,1,'black'
union select 4,2,2,'and'
union select 5,2,4,'white'

declare @phrase table
(phraseId int)

insert @phrase
select 1
union select 2

select phraseID
       ,phraseText AS completePhrase
FROM @phrase AS p
CROSS APPLY (select word + ' ' as [text()]
             from @words AS w
             where w.phraseID = p.phraseID
             for xml path('')
            ) as phrases (phraseText)
```

Comment: Good, but your assumption of a header record is unnecessary. For instance:

select phraseID,phraseText AS completePhrase
FROM (select distinct phraseId from @words) AS p
CROSS APPLY (select word + ' ' as [text()]
             from @words AS w
             where w.phraseID = p.phraseID
             for xml path('')
            ) as phrases (phraseText)

Comment: @spender - Isn't that exactly what I said at the start of my answer?

Comment: Sorry... missed that. Scratch my last comment!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used Lieven's second answer, but found that for certain string combinations, the `FOR XML PATH('')` trick causes problems to occur:

```
declare @phrases table
(
    id int
    ,phraseId int
    ,seqNum int
    ,word varchar(10)
)

insert 
    @phrases 
values
    (1,1,1,'hello'),
    (2,1,2,'world'),
    (3,2,1,'black'),
    (4,2,2,'and'),
    (5,2,3,'white')

SELECT  
    DISTINCT p1.PhraseID, 
    STUFF(
        ( 
            SELECT  
                ' ' + p2.word 
            FROM    
                @phrases AS p2 
            WHERE   
                p2.PhraseID = p1.PhraseID 
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, '') AS completePhrase
FROM      
    @phrases AS p1
ORDER BY  
    p1.PhraseID
```

works fine, but if the example uses characters that would need escaping were they used in an XML, problems occur. For instance, running the following data through it:

```
insert 
    @words 
values
    (1,1,1,'hello>'), --notice the less than symbol
    (2,1,2,'world'),
    (3,2,1,'black')
```

Gives

```
hello&gt; world
```

and also if the source table is declared out of order, an `order by` is required

A small mod to the original query fixes all:

```
SELECT  
    DISTINCT p1.PhraseID, 
    STUFF(
        ( 
            SELECT  
                ' ' + p2.word 
            FROM    
                @words AS p2 
            WHERE   
                p2.PhraseID = p1.PhraseID 
            ORDER BY
                p2.seqNum  --required
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        ).value('.','nvarchar(4000)'), 
        1, 
        1, 
        ''
    ) AS completePhrase
FROM      
    @words AS p1
ORDER BY  
    p1.PhraseID
```

(see [FOR XML PATH(''): Escaping "special" characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051362))